# Can not access REST endpoint in a custom Spring Boot starter

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I created a custom Spring Boot starter which provides some REST endpoints using `@RestController` annotation and an emply configuration class with `spring.factories` file is also included in the starter. However, when I tried to use the starter in another Spring Boot application, the REST endpoints always return `404` no matter in test with `MockMvc` or in running accessed by external tools (`curl` etc.).

May I know whether it is possible to seperate REST endpoint? If it is possible, am I missing anthing?

Edition 1
The controller class looks like:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/foo")
public class MyController {
    @GetMapping
    public String foo() {return "bar";}
}
```

and the configuration class looks like:

```java
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnClass(MyController.class)
public class MyRestAutoConfiguration {

}
```

The configutation class is correctly loaded when the application started.

Comment: Probably your starter is not activated. Please check your `@ConditionalOn` annotations over your starter's configuration and run your main application with `--debug`: in logs you'll see whether your autoconfiguration is enabled or not.

Comment: Can you provide the controller and the configuration classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from AutoConfiguration you need to tell Spring where to look for bean classes. So in your code you should either describe the controller as a method or use `@ComponentScan` annotation:

```java
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnClass(MyController.class)
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = {MyController.class})
public class MyRestAutoConfiguration {

}
```

or

```java
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnClass(MyController.class)
public class MyRestAutoConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public MyController tradeMacAuthTokenService() {
        return new MyController();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your `server.servlet.context-path`? Maybe it has some value e.g.  `server.servlet.context-path: /api`  and you need to access your endpoint as ` `localhost:8080/api/foo`. Also if you are using IntelliJ IDEA  you can use Services tab to see all the endpoints of your applicaiton.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. The first solution works for me. However, for the second one, `MyController` has been registered as a spring bean by `@RestController`, so providing another one by `@Bean` will casue errors in the custom starter.

Comment: Cool! Please rate and accept the answer to make it helpful for the rest of users.